# my website doesnt look the same in all browsers? it looks right in safari but not IE or firefox

Tags: html, tags, webbrowser-control

anyone have the code to ger websites to look right in IE and firefox?

Comment: Wrong tags and too little details.

Comment: This question requires d_tail. Would you like to buy a vowel?

Comment: Yes, you can take the code from me. Meet me at the fountain-of-life at the end of the rainbow. I usually go there in the evenings for coffee.

Comment: Yes, it won't look the same. You have to work hard to make it cross-browser compatible.

Comment: For browser incompatibility issues, try asking the question over at Doctype.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It's called hard work.

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and the [IE Developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) to help you.